# Calculate number of unique values in grouped matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, unique

I have a grouped data set that looks like this:

```
data = data.frame(group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                  c1 = c("A", "E", "A", "J", "L", "M", "L", "J"), 
                  c2 = c("B", "F", "F", "K", "B", "F", "T", "E"), 
                  c3 = c("C", "G", "C", "L", "C", "X", "C", "V"), 
                  c4 = c("D", "H", "I", "M", "D", "T", "I", "W"))
```

And I need to calculate the number of values in each row that are not duplicated within each group. For example, something that looks like this:

```
    group c1 c2 c3 c4 uniq.vals
1     1  A  B  C  D         2
2     1  E  F  G  H         3
3     1  A  F  C  I         1
4     1  J  K  L  M         4
5     2  L  B  C  D         2
6     2  M  F  X  T         3
7     2  L  T  C  I         1
8     2  J  E  V  W         4
```

The count for row 1 would be 2, because B and D do not show up in any of the other rows within group 1.

I am familiar with using group_by and summarize but I am having trouble extending that to this particular situation, which requires that each value be checked across multiple columns and rows. For example, n_distinct on its own would not work because I'm looking for non-duplicated values, not unique values.

Ideally the solution would also ignore NAs and not count them as duplicated or non-duplicated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, grouped by 'group', `replace` all the `duplicate` 'value' to `NA`, then grouped by row number, `summarise` to get the counts with `n_distinct` (number of distinct elements), and bind with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('c')) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(value = replace(value, duplicated(value)|duplicated(value,
     fromLast = TRUE), NA)) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(uniq.vals = n_distinct(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    select(uniq.vals) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)
```

-output

```
#   group c1 c2 c3 c4 uniq.vals
#1     1  A  B  C  D         2
#2     1  E  F  G  H         3
#3     1  A  F  C  I         1
#4     1  J  K  L  M         4
#5     2  L  B  C  D         2
#6     2  M  F  X  T         3
#7     2  L  T  C  I         1
#8     2  J  E  V  W         4
```

Comment: Thank you! The second option worked for me when translating to the real data set, which in place of letters has character strings of the form "firstname.lastname." For some reason the first option did not work and was not picking up on duplicated strings/names--i.e., it was returning uniq.vals that reflected the number of non-NAs in each row. Can you think of any reason why that might be the case? (PS. my apologies, I intended to upvote I just hit enter on this comment before I was finished writing it).

Comment: @addison Let me check that

Comment: @Addison sorry, I was copying the output from my second solution.  I know the reason why this is having an issue.  I looked at your post earlier and was kind of confused because some values were inconsistent.  The reason is that the duplicate checking is by column and not for the entire group

Answer (score 3):

In base R you would do:

```
a <- tapply(unlist(data[-1]), data$group[row(data[-1])],table)

data$uniq.vals <-  c(by(data, seq(nrow(data)),
                        function(x)sum(a[[x[,1]]][unlist(x[-1])]<2)))

 group c1 c2 c3 c4 uniq.vals
1     1  A  B  C  D         2
2     1  E  F  G  H         3
3     1  A  F  C  I         1
4     1  J  K  L  M         4
5     2  L  B  C  D         2
6     2  M  F  X  T         3
7     2  L  T  C  I         1
8     2  J  E  V  W         4
```

Note that in your case, row 3 should have 1 since only I is the unique value